# Error to compile lstlisting

Tags: lstlisting

I'm trying put this code to tex document:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Definição dos UUIDs no microcontrolador,captionpos=b]
#define SERVICE_UUID                       "ab0828b1-198e-4351-b779-901fa0e0371e"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID_ID    "1a220d0a-6b06-4767-8692-243153d94d85"
#define DESCRIPTOR_UUID_EVENTO ﻿"c996a2b1-fe24-4b57-98b7-b06227110244"
#define DESCRIPTOR_UUID_ID           "ec6e1003-884b-4a1c-850f-1cfce9cf6567"
\end{lstlisting}
```

but when I compile this, the follow error occurs:

[image]

I've other `lstlisting` on my document and all works fine, just it not works.

Comment: You're missing a `}` after `microcontrolador`

Comment: Thank you so much, but other error occurs now: `Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence. #define DESCRIPTOR_UUID_EVENTO "`

Comment: There is a spurious U+FEFF character between `EVENTO` and `"`. Select from `TO` up to `"c` and retype that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The brace `{` after `caption=` has no matching `}`.
2. Between `EVENTO` and `"c99" a spurious character U+FEFF (ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE) has crept in. Remove it.

How did I find the invisible character? I copied the line from your code and pasted it at https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/

After clicking “Convert”, the box U+hex reports

```
EVENTO U+FEFF"c996
```

Comment: Excellent tool for catch spurious spaces, thanks as always!! `:)`.